# Subsection numbering: use letters only

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I have to format section and subsection numbers as follows:

(I use `article` class.)

```
I. Section
A. Subsection
B. Subsection

II. Section
A. Subsection
B. Subsection
```

I use the package `sectsty`. At the moment, the code reads like this:

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\normalfont\centering\scshape}
\subsectionfont{\normalfont\itshape}
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\Alph{subsection}}
```

But if I do that, I get:

```
I Section
I.A Subsection
```

etc.

How do I get rid of the Roman numeral in the subsection number, and how do I add the trailing dots?

Comment: Well, delete `\thesection` from the re-definition of \thesubsection.

Comment: Thank you! Cecile

Comment: As for your other question, please consider accepting the provided answer. This way the process is "closed".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked,

> How do I get rid of the roman numeral in the subsection?

You're very close. Just change

```
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\Alph{subsection}}
```

to

```
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Alph{subsection}}
```

i.e., omit the `\thesection.` prefix which expands to `\Roman{section}.`.

Aside: Observe that the numbering issue is not related to the use or non-use of the `sectsty` package.

---

*Addendum*: To affix "dots" (aka periods, full stops) to `I`, `A`, etc, I suggest you add the following code to the preamble:

```
% Method proposed in "The LaTeX Companion", 2nd ed.:
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname\space}%    default
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}}%  enable individual control
\newcommand\section@cntformat{\thesection.\space}       % section level
\newcommand\subsection@cntformat{\thesubsection.\space} % subsection level
\makeatother
```

This somewhat complicated-looking approach preserves the ability to create cross-references to sections and subsections without pesky dots suddenly showing up in the cross-reference. (That's exactly what would happen if one set, naively, `\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}.}` instead of just the current `\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}`.)

---

Here's the output of an MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\normalfont\centering\scshape}
\subsectionfont{\normalfont\itshape}

\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Alph{subsection}}

% Method proposed in "The LaTeX Companion", 2nd ed.:
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname\space}%    default
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}}%  individual control
\newcommand\section@cntformat{\thesection.\space}       % section level
\newcommand\subsection@cntformat{\thesubsection.\space} % subsection level
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\subsection{First Subsection}
\subsection{Second Subsection}
\end{document}
```